# wkhtmltopdf with '?' in URL

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

My question is about use of '?' with wkhtmltopdf

Using StackOverflow advice, I have wkhtmltopdf working as invoked from a 
php webpage...for example this works as expected:

```
$exec_string = "xvfb-run -a -s "."\"-screen 0, 1024x768x24 \""." 
wkhtmltopdf http://example.com temp.pdf";

exec($exec_string);
```

However, if I add to the URL like this:

http://example.com/?page=clients

wkhtmltopdf ignores the `page=clients` and produces a pdf identical to the above result. I even tried surrounding with " as

```
...\"http://example.com/?page=clients \"...
```

but still no good.

How can I force wkhtmltopdf to pickup the the ?page=clients piece?

Comment: Why is there a blank after your address? have you tried `"http://example.com/?page=clients\"`?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered my problem is more complicated than simply wkhtmltopdf not recognizing ?page=clients.

The website that the page belongs to does 'security' checks prior to displaying a page like this. An experiment done outside this framework shows me that wkhtmltopdf does indeed pickup the page=clients specification.